# Managing lots of Enums across multiple application layers

Tags: c#, enums

I have an application that requires the use of a lot of different enumerations. The application can be devided into various layers. For the sake of the example let's assume three layers: a 3rd party analytics library, the application business logic and the UI/presentation logic.

In many cases all layers may have the need for an enum representing the same concept. Let's take a payment frequency for instance. (e.g. annual, semi-annual, quarterly etc...).
The 3rd party library provides its own enum, the various classes in the business logic layer would need a similar enum, and finally the UI layer may need it for presenting various choices in dropdowns etc...

Now, normally I'd like to shield the user of each layer from its internal dependencies and implementation details by not exposing types from internal dependcies in the public interfaces of the layer. That means that even though the interaction with the 3rd party lib requires the use of its own "Frequency" enum, I'd need to create an equivalent "Frequency" enum for the business layer and potencially another one for the UI layer...

All of this requires a lot of mapping back and forth, with potencially lot of additional mapper classes. The adventage on the other hand is that each layer may decide to exclude values it does not need or support from its own version of the enum...

Now since I have to deal with a *lot* of enums, I was just wondering if this is generally a good thing to do, or am I just overcomplicating things?

Answer (score 4):

I would say you're overcomplicating things. Why not have a separate project for shared entities like this? You can then have each assembly reference your `Common` project to reference the necessary enums and still have them all totally independent of each other.

Comment: That's not a good suggestion. It's better to have enums close to the entities that will use them. For example, `Order` may have an `OrderType` enum, which makes sense to place them in one folder of the project. This makes it easier to change them according to the business logic. It's not appealing to pool such different enums in one `Common` place.

Comment: @MassoodKhaari Splitting the enums out into separate libraries allows the loose coupling of the BLL and UI layers without code duplication - it's a perfectly good suggestion. Putting two things in one folder *is* a good idea, as long as those things are intended to be closely coupled, which is not the case in this instance (and in this instance will actually harm the separation of concerns within the solution). Your criticism isn't really valid.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i may be missunderstanding you but, actualy, you will just need, in data layer, which is viewd by the logic layer, your enuns. Using your own example, you would have a column names `PaymentFrequency` in a table. Your table should be mapped in your data layer for this specific field, so you'll create a enum and the type of the column PaymentFrequency - by this moment an attribute of your table class or entity - will be setted as the enum created for this purpose. So, when you point your logic layer to request/access your data layer, you'll need to understand this same enum - so, if your using a DAL layer between logic and data layers, i recommend you to create the enuns in a separate class/file. Well, in your logic layer - by using the enum options - you'll populate a simple `Combo` component with the enum options, so, you'll be presening the options in the UI by hiding all your layers, in a way that users won't know you are actually using a enum to handle the options.

I hope this help. Sorry - really sorry - for this ***** bad english!
If this don't help, post some cod examples to be easier to help you =)